# How to extract section numbers in a docx document using python-docx?

Tags: python-docx

I have a docx document which is structured into sections and subsections e.g.

> **Section A**
>
> texttexttext
>
> 1. texttexttext
>
>    1.1  texttexttext
> 2. texttexttext
>
>    (a) texttexttext

I want to use python-docx to extract the text.  It is easy to get the text in the paragraphs but I do not know how to get the text of the section headings (e.g. "1." and "(a)" etc.).  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

How easy it will be will depend on how rigorous the document author has been in constructing the document.

It the best case, the author has used styles for all section headings, and then you can just parse through the paragraphs picking out those with "Heading 1" style, for example.

```
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if paragraph.style.name == 'Heading 1':
        print(paragraph.text)
```

If the author instead applied character formatting like **bold** and font size to designate headings, your job will be tougher as these are much less likely to uniquely identify headings.

Comment: What if there's a table on below one of the headers? how can you identify that that table belongs to the first header?

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you to use `sections` like the following example:

```
     document = Document()

     sections = document.sections

     sections

     <docx.parts.document.Sections object at 0x1deadbeef>

     len(sections)

     3

     section = sections[0]

     section

     <docx.section.Section object at 0x1deadbeef>
    for section in sections:

        print(section.start_type)

    NEW_PAGE (2)

    EVEN_PAGE (3)

    ODD_PAGE (4)
```

Comment: I believe the author of the question is actually asking about "headings" rather than `sections` (as defined in MS Word documents).