# How to catch the list number for each paragraph

Tags: python, docx

I try to use python docx to read word file content. 
For example: Attachment demo word file, it contains several paragraphs. Some paragraph contains a heading number, like 1.3, 1.4.1 etc. 
[image]

My program is try to open the docx, and search a keyword in each paragraph. If the keyword exist in dedicate paragraph, print out that paragraph and its heading number. 
[image]
However, it fail to print the heading number. For example, I search keyword "wall", it only print out paragraph with "wall", but no heading number 1.4.1. 
I need the number too.

```
def search_word(filename,word):
#open the word file
document=Document(filename)
#read every paragraph
l=[paragraph.text.encode('utf-8') for paragraph in document.paragraphs]
result=[]
for i in l:
    i=i.strip()
    i=str(i)
    pattern=re.compile(r"(.*)(%s)(.*)"%word,re.I|re.M)
    rel=pattern.findall(i)
    if  len(rel):
        result.append(rel)
print(filename+"="*30+"Search Result"+"="*30)
print("-"*150)
for k in result:
    for m in k:  
        print("".join(m).strip('b\'')+"\n"*1)
print("-"*150+"\n"*2)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "list number"?

Comment: For example:  List 1 : aaaa    List 2: bbbb.   List 3:  cccc   I want to get the list 1 2 3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54177892/7919597

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38776898/7919597

Comment: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/471

Comment: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/590#issue-394929997

Comment: This one https://stackoverflow.com/a/38776898/7919597 could provide a workaround if your document is well formated. You can count the occurrences of each type and derive the number from there.

Comment: @Joe Thanks your suggestion. But I need to clarify my problem first, I edit my question. I want to print the paragraph with heading number too.

Comment: @Joe I also try to use a bad way that change the docx file to HTML first, then use beautifulsoup to seach all <span> label text. This can get heading number and paragraph one by one, but bring new problem in search result, I still fail to link up the search result with heading number.... too bad... Sorry, I am fresh man in python.

Comment: You can do the same without beautifulsoup. You iterate through the paragraphs as stated in the links above. During that iteration you can do the numbering. If heading1 has appeared twice then you are in `2.` if below that there are two entries with `heading2` these are the chapters `2.1` and `2.2`.

Comment: No, this doesn't help. It reassign a new heading no. , not call its original no.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find a stupid way to catch each paragraph heading and its content.
I convert the docx to HTML first, then using beautifulsoup & re to search my keyword.

```
def search_file(file,word):
global output_content
output_content=output_content+"\n"+"*"*30+file.split("\\")[-1]+" Search Result" +"*"*30+"\n"*2
url=file
htmlfile = open(url, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
demo = htmlfile.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(demo,'lxml')
all_content=soup.find_all(['h1','h2','h3', 'h4', 'h5','p'])
new_list=[]
for item in all_content:
    if item.text not in new_list:
        new_list.append(item.text)
dic1={}   #Build a empty dic to store each clause no, and its detail content from every paragraph
Target=""
content=""
for line in new_list:
    line=str(line.replace("\n"," "))
    pattern=re.compile(r"(^[1-9].+)")   #Judge the paragraph whether start with heading no. 
    line_no=bool(pattern.search(line))  
    if line_no:                                          #If the paragraph start with heading no
        dic1[Target]=content               #Save the conent to heading no. in dic.
        Target=line                                  
        content=""
        continue
    else:                                                   #if the paragraph is detail, not heading line, 
        content=content+line+"\n"     # save the content
        continue
result=[]  #The keyword search from the dic item, if the keyword in the item, shall print the dic key and item at the same time.     
for value in dic1.values():
    pattern=re.compile(r".*%s.*"%word,re.I|re.M)
    rel=pattern.findall(value)
    if len(rel):
        result.append((list(dic1.keys())[list(dic1.values()).index(value)]))
        result.append(list(rel))
        result.append("\n")
return print_result(file,result)
```

def print_result(file,nums):
    global output_content
    for i in nums:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            print_result(file,i)
        else:
            output_content=output_content+i